# Does SiCl2 exist and its possible structure

Tags: molecular-structure, halides, covalent-compounds

It's known that the elements in IVA all have valence +2 and +4. I also know there exists $\ce{GeCl2}$ and $\ce{SnCl2}$. So my question is does $\ce{SiCl2}$, or even $\ce{CCl2}$ exist? If yes, what about their molecular structure?

In addition, what makes +2 valence in $\ce{Ge}, \ce{Sn}$ more stable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorocarbene), $\ce{CCl2}$, where carbon is in the +2 oxidation state, does exist but it is fleeting due to its high reactivity.

I was able to find a reference on the [analogous dichlorosilylene](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00347a061), and I also found some information on [difluorosilylene, also known as silicon difluoride](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed053p696), both of which have silicon in the +2 state and react similarly to a carbene.

**So yes, both $\ce{CCl2}$ and $\ce{SiCl2}$ exist where the central atom in the +2 oxidation state.**

Tin(II) chloride fill its octet by way of either  bridging chloride bonds in the crystal structure or hydration bonds in water (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_chloride#Chemical_structure) images). The structure of solid $\ce{GeCl2}$ [isn't given](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium_dichloride), but I would expect something similar. I'll update if I find anything.